# Unexpected token '(' при 'npx sequelize-cli db:migrate'

Tags: node.js, база-данных, typescript, webstorm, sequelize.js

Создаю новый проект.
Ввожу команду `npm install sequelize`
Далее идет `npm install --save-dev sequelize-cli`
После установки пакетов sequelize, устанавливаю пакет mysql2

```
npm install mysql2
```

Далее идет команда

```
npx sequelize-cli init
```

и команды типа

```
npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name User --attributes firstName:string,lastName:string,email:string
```

для создания моделей. В config файле меняю данные для своей бд
и запускаю миграцию командой `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`
Выдает ошибку

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 12.22.9, CLI: 6.6.1, ORM: 6.33.0]

Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
Using environment "development".

ERROR: Unexpected token '('
```

Не пойму на что он жалуется, раньше такая схема всегда работала, сижу на linux, ide webstorm. Пробовал устанавливать npm пакеты старых версий, все тоже самое.
Файл index моделей

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const process = require('process');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.js')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config.options);
}

fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(file => {
      return (
          file.indexOf('.') !== 0 &&
          file !== basename &&
          file.slice(-3) === '.js' &&
          file.indexOf('.test.js') === -1
      );
    })
    .forEach(file => {
      const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
      db[model.name] = model;
    });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: Вы уверены в этой строке `require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)` - синтаксически похоже на то, что из файла будет импорт функции и ее вызов, а затем результат вызова будет сохранен в переменную(там вроде объект должен вернуться, судя по синтаксису)

Comment: Это код созданный автоматически. По идеи оно должно работать

Comment: Что значит - код созданный автоматически? Создан кем/чем и зачем? По чьей идее оно должно работать - можно озвучить эту идею?

Comment: Команда npx sequelize-cli init создает базовые файлы.
Делал все по документации от сюда https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/
Раньше работал, без понятия, что поменялось

Comment: Если вы уверены в предоставленном коде и он точно из коробки и изменений в него вы не вносили, то, возможно, ошибка в файлах, которые вы загружаете в методе forEach. В файлах дожна быть фукнция. Тут только выискивать глазами, если в тексте ошибки нет явного указания на файл и строку, где ошибка произошла. Сама ошибка говорит, что в коде встретилась скобка, хотя ее там быть не должно.

Comment: Я снес linux, поставил винду и все заработало)